# unexpected output in plotting ROC curve for SVM classifier

Tags: r, plot, roc

While i'm trying to plot SVM using ROC curve for discrete classification it didn't produce a curve matched with its accuracy rate . while the acc. rate produced for SVM using confusion matrix was 88.1% 
 and it produced the following curve.

[ROC Curve for SVM in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciyA0.png)

also i calculated the area under curve (AUC) it gives me 1.0 this means that the acc. rate has to be 100 % not 88.1%.

here is the code that i used to produce it

> x <- subset(mov[3522:4521,-17])
>
> q <- (mov[3522:4521,17])
>
> svm_model1 <- svm(x,q,cost = .1 , gamma =.5,probability = TRUE)
>
> a <-  predict(svm_model1,type="prob", newdata = mov[3522:4521,-17],
>   probability = TRUE)
>
> library(ROCR)
>
> rocc <-prediction (attr(a, "probabilities")[,2],mov[3522:4521,'y'])
>
> per <- performance(rocc, "tpr","fpr")
>
> plot(per,colorize=T,lwd= 3,main="ROC curve for SVM")

i found a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37795/roc-curve-for-discrete-classifiers-like-svm-why-do-we-still-call-it-a-curve) that could be related but unfortunately i couldn't get it

does anyone know why i got this ROC curve?

Comment: Learn to capitalize correctly. Learn to post [MCVE].

Comment: This seems to match. Please have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105501/understanding-roc-curve

Comment: @Calimo thanks for your help, it helps me to understand ROC curve more but i still couldn't find an answer for my question. is that normal to have a curve that couldn't match with the accuracry rate for a discrete classifier.

Comment: @MennatallahIbrahim ROC AUC and accuracy are totally different things. As explained in the link above, accuracy represents one point in the ROC space. What makes you think the value of one point should be equal to an area under multiple points?

Comment: Also as mentioned by 42 you need to post a complete example. Including how you computed the accuracy, which you obviously don't do optimally.